# TypeError: 'property' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, poo

Estoy programando el juego del tateti utilizando POO en Python y me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Now playing: Human (X)
It's your turn X. Enter a number [1-9]: 2 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\-----\Desktop\Cursos\Python\Práctica\Proyectos\Juegos\tic_tac_toe\tic_tac_toe.py", line 141, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\-----\Desktop\Cursos\Python\Práctica\Proyectos\Juegos\tic_tac_toe\tic_tac_toe.py", line 137, in main
    game.play()
  File "c:\Users\-----\Desktop\Cursos\Python\Práctica\Proyectos\Juegos\tic_tac_toe\tic_tac_toe.py", line 114, in play
    self.player_move(human)
  File "c:\Users\-----\Desktop\Cursos\Python\Práctica\Proyectos\Juegos\tic_tac_toe\tic_tac_toe.py", line 96, in player_move
    elif Board.board[move] != Fields.FIELD_EMPTY.value:
TypeError: 'property' object is not subscriptable
```

¿Qué es lo que está mal?
Repositorio del código: https://github.com/xSyrax123/Tateti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas usando la clase `Board` en lugar de un objeto de esa clase en

```
if Board.board[4] == Fields.FIELD_EMPTY.value:
```

Esta es la definición de la clase `Board`, eliminando todo lo irrelevante

```
class Board:
    def __init__(self):
        self._board = [" "] * 9

    @property
    def board(self):
        return self._board

    @board.setter
    def board(self, board):
        self._board = board
```

`board`es una *propiedad* de la clase, o sea, un atributo que tiene *setter* y *getter* para cambiar/recuperar su contenido.

La solución es reemplazar la clase `Board`
Podemos definir un objeto (una *instancia*) de esa clase y examinar que nos da usar `board`

```
a = Board()
print(a.board) => [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```

Entonces, `a.board` es una lista, y por tanto, `a.board[4]` es una expresión válida y produce `' '`.

Lo que tú escribiste es

```
b = Board
print(b.board) => <property object at 0x7fee242664f0>
```

en lugar de crear un objeto de clase `Board`, creastes una referencia a la clase, y por tanto, `b.board` ahora es la propiedad de la clase, no el contenido.

Probablemente debas reemplazar la línea con

```
if self.board.board[4] == Fields.FIELD_EMPTY.value:
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!